# Trying to Connect to MySQL local host server but browser does not load and asks me to download a file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, download

Total noob here apologizes in advance.

When I test my localhost connection in my SQL it says its good and server status is green. However, when I go to the URL at the top and attempt to navigate to localhost:3306, instead of the page displaying "This webpage is not available" as I expect, it does not navigate to the page and instead gives me a pop up asking me to download "download.file" a 1KB file which I can't open.

I'm trying to learn Rails

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, it's difficult to help you without any examples of the page you're talking about, the controller code, etc. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Apache server. For example install XAMPP.